# How about receiving a notification whenever the person asking the question comments on the question thread?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Many times, it so happens that new users often forgets to link usernames while commenting on their question thread.

It would be nice to receive notification whenever the person who has asked the question comments on the question thread - so that anyone who has commented before is aware of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that new users often forget to link usernames

Not sure I follow this...

> It would be nice to receive notification whenever the person who has asked the question comments on the question thread

The [notifications FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) mentions:

> - The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment.
> - If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if
>     @name is forgotten.
> - Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list
>     cannot be notified

So if *anyone* has commented or edited on post - the person will be notified.

Comment: If i see a question, and i ask him to clarify, then dat person (new user) comments , but i wont get a notification coz he has not directed that comment to me using @

Comment: @pratik you will - `Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on`

Comment: Is it, i m not getting such comments since i have joined :(

Comment: you haven't done an at to me, and I got a notification. You should be getting a notification now for this comment too.

Comment: @pratik when **more than one person** posted comment then you are right: nobody will get notification unless `@` is used. Notifying everyone will create too much "noise" so I won't try to suggest such feature: I'm sure the developers thought through it and reached wise decision.